# Abruptly rising up in the bed?

Tags: word-choice, word-request

I usually feel I've got a good grasp of English, but this stomped me...  I need a word/phrase for the *action* of a person laying (stretched out) on his back on a bed, and who *abruptly* rise to a sitting position - ie. he rises his back/torso, while his legs remains outstretched on the bed.

```
He goes from this:

L__ __O
=======

To this:

    O
    |
L__ |
======
```

Personally I'd use something like "He shot **off** the bed" - but that doesn't convey that his legs are still in the bed and only his back is off it... besides, it sort of suggests that he's hovering over the bed... or that he's got out of the bed (and is standing on the floor.  In any case, it's easy to confuse with "He shot **out of** the bed".

"He abruptly **sat up** in bed" could perhaps work, but could it be interpreted as sitting on the bed - as if it was a chair - with feet on the floor?  "He abruptly **rose up** in bed" could perhaps work, but could be easily be misunderstood as "rose **from**"...

So, are there any word/phrase *specifically* for this - or a way to make one of my suggestions clearer?

Comment: I think "He abruptly sat up in bed." is fine. If his feet were off the bed, I would use ""He abruptly sat up *on the edge of* the bed." BTW, this *stumped* you.

Comment: Yeah, to a native speaker, "sat up in bed" is only going to imply "came to a sitting position, while still in the bed", and not "sat on the edge of the bed."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In English, as luck would have it, there is a term which is typically used to describe exactly what you specify:

> Bolt upright.

The [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/bolt-upright) has:

> **vertical and extremely straight:**
>    *She woke up and sat bolt upright in bed, terrified by her dream.*

In fact, *bolt upright* is seldom used without being followed by *in bed.*